# Not able to start database instance

Tags: database, oracle, initialization, instance

```
C:\Users\H6W>sqlplus EV6_PASS_USER/EV6_PASS_USER@orcl1906

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Fri Jul 31 14:38:28 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

I have waited long time but still database instance does not start. System was shut down to low battery. After startup of machine, oracle listeners, I have also started database instance orcl1906 through windows services, database instance shows started there. But in reality, not able to start sql session using database user.

Comment: The Oracle Database alert.log should tell you exactly what is going on. Look for alert*.log in your Oracle Software install directory.

Comment: @BjarteBrandt, thank you very much for suggestion below is content from aler.log can you plesae suggest                                     
      OCROSD]ut_read_reg:2:ocr registry key SOFTWARE\Oracle\ocr cannot be opened. error 2

Comment: I tried to forcible mount database by alter database mount. It seems that redo logs are corrupted since it was hard shutdown a day before. Hence I decided to create fresh instance since it is corrupted.